# Using Windows GUI to input decimal values and display the corresponding hexadecimal values

Tags: c, dev-c++

How can I retrieve in-putted integer values from a textbox in windows API design in C  to convert them to string and then display these values in hexadecimal number  through a static label in C.

CODE:

```
    GetWindowText(hwndtext1, hexval, 256);

    for (i = sizeof(hexval); i >= 0; i--)
      {     
        buf[i] = atoll(hexval);

        ulltoa(buf[i], szBuffer, 16);
        SetWindowText(hwndStatic3, szBuffer);

        }
```

-------edit------
I want to be able to display hexadecimal numbers based on the decimal input. Therefore on my GUI developed in c, I am able to write decimal numbers in the text box and I want to display the hexadecimal value for the decimal in a separate textbox.

-------------EDIT-----------------

I have fix the code slightly and  now only the last byte of the hexadecimal number is being displayed.

for example. if the decimal input is 2000.... the hexadecimal output is showing only d0.
when the correct hexadecimal output should be 7d0.

Comment: sorry Im not sure I get it ... you want to convert From a HEX String Representation of a number to Decimal String Representation, right? please edit the question to be cleared and remove the misleading Get/SetWindowText References

Comment: You are mixing too many different aspects here. There's text box manipulation, string processing, converting from string to integer, converting from integer to hexadecimal string. Which aspect are you struggling with? Try to break down the problem into the bits you can do, and the bits you cannot do.

Comment: @user2075927 What is `case 1` and is this code in the proper place? ie are you sure this code is being called when you press a button?

Comment: Case 1 is just part of the switch case statement I created

Comment: @user2075927 yeah, most people reading this will have seen `switch` statements before. But the `1` is just a magic number http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) which means *nothing* to the rest of us. So if it's not important, leave it out, and if it is important use a descriptive name for it.

Comment: `SetWindowText(hwndStatic3, buf[256]);` should just be buf, you are passing it the last character value in buf, which at best will be '\0'

Comment: Please stop adding the windows-api-codepack tag which has no bearing on the question at all. The Windows API CodePack is for .net. Your question is tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

This function converts integer value to hex string in 0x0 format.  The first int is your number the second actually takes a char (typically 'a' or 'A') to determine the 10 to 15 characters.

```
char *dtox(int d, int c){
static char buf[80];
if (0==d)return "0x0";
int p=0;
c-=10;
if (0>d) { buf[p++]='-'; d=-d;}
buf[p++]='0';buf[p++]='x';
unsigned int i=1<<28;
while (i>d) i/=16;
while (0<i){
   ((d/i)>9) ? (buf[p++]=(c+(d/i))) : (buf[p++]=('0'+(d/i)));
   if (i<=d) d=d%i;
   i/=16;
}
buf[p]=0;
return buf;
}
```

I only post this since itoa is a non-standard function, the real problem is probably from passing buf[256] (a char value) instead of buf (a char array, a.k.a. string) that your function is expecting

Comment: I adapted this from a decimal to string function, so you may want to do further optimization if your compiler doesn't already convert integer division and modulus to bit operations.

Comment: Er, why `static char buf[80]`?

Comment: No reason, it was like that in the original decimal version... Just cut/pasted